# How do I use React Router <Link to> from antd table column

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, antd

I am using react router, and antd in my project. I am using  from antd. I display a column and on click of this column, I want to reroute the user to another details page, using this

```
<Route>
    {/*<Redirect to="/pages/mypage">*/}
    {/*  {text}*/}
    {/*</Redirect>*/}
    <Link to='/pages/mypage'>
      {text}
    </Link>
  </Route>
```

This does not work and gives a 404 error. In addition to this code, I have a file called router.js which has an entry to `/pages/mypage`

Can anyone help me understand how to get React Router route user to another page by clicking a cell in a table column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to click on cell, you can make your columns definition something like this:

```
const columns = [
  {dataIndex: 'email', onCell: () => ({ onClick: () => history.push('/pages/mypage')})}
]
```

If you want to click on a link inside the cell, you can make it like:

```
const columns = [
  {dataIndex: 'email', render: (data) => <Link to="pages/mypage">{data}</Link>}
]
```

Keep in mind the following:

- In both exemples, I put the dataIndex as email, you should use the pathName for the property you want to render on that column
- In the render method, `data` is the value for the property you put on dataIndex, if dataIndex is undefined, data will be the entire rowObject.
- `history` can be accessed from a hook or context in react router hitory.push is bassicaly the same as if the user clicked a link, but it can be used outside the react flow.

Comment: Hi Arthur,
this worked,
 ```const columns = [
  {dataIndex: 'email', render: (data) => <Link to="pages/mypage">{data}</Link>}
]```

The mistake that I was making was that for the path I was entering 'pages/myPage', and it should've been 'pages/my-page'